# I keep getting the errors... 'use of unresolved identifier' and 'Type gameType has no member pause game'

Tags: ios, swift

I created a button to pause my game and I'm trying to make some actions for it. 
So I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, all other 'solutions' on this website haven't been working for me, so could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong, or rather what I'm not doing.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

enum gameType {
case easy
case medium
case hard
case player2
case impossible
}

func pauseGame() {         // HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERRORS... IN THIS FUNCTION
    self.isPaused = true
    currentGameType = gameType.pauseGame
    self.physicsWorld.speed = 0
    self.speed = 0.0
}

class MenuVC : UIViewController {

@IBAction func Player2(_ sender: Any) {
    moveToGame(game: .player2)
}

@IBAction func Easy(_ sender: Any) {
    moveToGame(game: .easy)
}
@IBAction func Medium(_ sender: Any) {
    moveToGame(game: .medium)

}
@IBAction func Hard(_ sender: Any) {
    moveToGame(game: .hard)
}

@IBAction func Impossible(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    moveToGame(game: .impossible)
}


func moveToGame(game : gameType) {
    let gameVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "gameVC") as! GameViewController

    currentGameType = game

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gameVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a lot which makes no sense. Your functions uses `self`, so it should be an *instance method* of some class. It accesses properties  `isPaused`, `speed`,  `physicsWorld`, so it probably should be an instance method of a subclass of `SKPhysicsWorld`, which is nowhere to be seen in your code.

Comment: Could you tell me how I make an instance method of a subclass SKPhysicsWorld please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your file, `gameType` is an [enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html). That means that there are a finite set of *cases* that it can have (the game type can either be easy, medium, hard, etc.) In your code, you're attempting to use a case called `pauseGame`, but if you look at the definition of `gameType` there's no case with that name. So you either need to a) add a `pauseGame` case to `gameType` (does it make sense for `pauseGame` to be a "kind" of game?) or not set the `gameType` inside your `pauseGame` function.

My instinct is that you don't actually want to change the type of the game when the user pauses it, so you can probably just get rid of that line. Also, a note on style -- it's good to start the names of types with capital letters to distinguish them from functions and local variables (so `GameType` instead of `gameType`.)

Comment: Ok thank you, but do you know why I keep getting the error '' use of unresolved identifier self"? If so, could you please tell me how to fix it.

Comment: Where is this happening? Also, if the answer is correct, could you please mark it as correct?

Comment: It's happening on the pauseGame function, and yeah sure!

Comment: The reason it's happening in `pauseGame` is because it is a [free function](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html). If you want it to be "part" of an object you need to use an [instance method](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-ID234) instead. For instance, if `self` is supposed to be the `MenuVC` then `pauseGame` needs to be defined inside the body of `MenuVC` (inside the braces.)

Comment: Ok thank you, I fixed that error, but in the same function inside the brackets, I get three different errors...

Comment: Value of type 'MenuVC' has no member 'isPaused'

Comment: and the same just with 'physicsWorld'

Comment: And no member 'speed'

Comment: I'd like to help, but it sounds like you don't have a very clear idea of how your game is supposed to work. I'd suggest looking at some sample code from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/DemoBots/Introduction/Intro.html) or [Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/145318/spritekit-swift-3-tutorial-beginners) and trying to copy some of the patterns you see there.